# Should I leave the water bottle tip open or shut while in the cage?

Tags: technique, hydration

When I'm riding (all road, never trails) I leave the tip on my water bottle shut. When I take a drink, I pull the tip open with my teeth, squirt some water, and then bump it against my slightly-opened teeth to shut the tip again.

I do it because the tip of my bottle will often get dirty, and I'll have to wipe it off with my shirt before drinking. If I leave it open grime would get inside the tip of the bottle.

It is a bit tedious, but I'm now used to it. Is this standard practice?

Comment: I tried to just reply "Yerp." but that was too short.  So, yes.

Comment: That would be totally normal.  If you're upside down or if your bottle falls on the road, its more likely to retain the liquid with the lid closed.  Plus the closed lid will be more aero than an open lid.

Comment: Personally I close the lid with my right hand while putting the bottle back in the cage, but whatever works for you.

Comment: That which does not kill you makes you stronger... I tend not to be too anal about getting the top closed... but when I have reason to be, I close the mouth piece by pressing the bottle against my hip on the way back to the water bottle mount.

Comment: I have found getting a bottle with a pressure valve remedies this process, the self sealing squeeze valves are awesome in my opinion, but it it falls and you run it over its going to squirt all your water out..

Comment: You're over-thinking this.

Comment: Yeah, with the pull-spout bottles it's easy to open the spout with your teeth and close it by bumping it against your body somewhere.  So it makes sense to keep it closed (when not drinking), as very little effort is involved (and it's not a distraction).  Bottles with flip lids, etc, are a different matter.  But this isn't really a life-and-death matter, regardless.

Comment: Get a water bottle that you don't have to pull open; https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B015DJF6HO/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o08_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote David Richerby: *You're over-thinking this*.

Most people close their bottles most of the time.

I'm not one to worry about a little "gunk", but I close my bottle more than half the time. I almost never wipe it (heh, I almost never wash it :-)

Not fanatical about it though. If I'm taking a quick swig before a corner then I'll just jamb the bottle back, whether the top's open or closed, before I get to the corner.

That can happen a lot, because I drink a little, often.